# How to convert time in string format into decimal in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie in C# programming and I need your help on this one.I have a string with a value of "12:45:00" and I would like to convert it into decimal with two decimal places.

Comment: "Decimal with the two places" what is the *time unit*? Can you provide an example?

Comment: time unit is in hours:minutes:seconds

Comment: Any *sample* how do you want to make it into *decimal with two places*. For example, given 12:45:00 what will be the output --> ?????

Comment: the output would be 12.45 since i'll be using it to compute for the gross income

Comment: Hmm. 12:45 in hh:mm would surely be 12.75 hours, not 12.45 hours...

Comment: could you help me with the syntax?? Convert.ToDecimal doesn't work

Comment: What would you expect to get for `12:34:56` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Why'd you delete your answer, it looks correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt Probably he does not know what should be a result for when seconds part is not zero. IMHO, probably _even_ OP does not  know this either.

Comment: @BenVoigt Soner is correct - I didn't think I had enough information to answer correctly.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Based on "i'll be using it to compute the gross income", the *right* answer is 12.75, and OP simply didn't think this through (or doesn't actually know how to calculate pay for minutes based on hourly rate by hand).

Answer (score 1):

Though you can actually use `DateTime` struct for your case, *but* since your `string` does not contain `date` info, I think the easiest way would be to use `string.Split` instead.

```
string[] strs = "12:45:00".Split(':'); //will give you 12, 45, and 00
double val = Convert.ToDouble(strs[0]) + Convert.ToDouble(strs[1]) / 60 + Convert.ToDouble(strs[2]) / 3600;
```

Then to print it in two decimal values, simply do:

```
val.ToString("F2"); //you will get 12.75
```

Or, to get `12.45`, then simply do:

```
double val = Convert.ToDouble(strs[0]) + Convert.ToDouble(strs[1]) / 100; //note 100 here - second doesn't matter here
```

Comment: Looks like OP wants `12:45` not `12:75` based on the comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684633/how-to-convert-time-in-string-format-into-decimal-in-c#comment59046787_35684633

Comment: @SonerGönül that's pretty strange for time unit *hours* :S don't you think? but well, I updated my answer to include that anyway...

Comment: @SonerGönül That makes no sense when calculating gross income given a duration in hours and an hourly rate (which is what I think the OP is trying to do). I can think of no case where using a double value of 12.45 to represent a duration of 12:45 makes sense in the context of calculating gross income.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Exactly. That's why I think voting to close is a better option instead of try to give an answer which not making sense question.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to convert a duration in hours, minutes and (optionally) seconds into hours, you can do that like so:

```
double answer = TimeSpan.Parse("12:45:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TotalHours;
Console.WriteLine(answer); // Prints 12.75
```

This is the value that you can use along with an hourly rate to calculate a gross income.

Note: It would be incorrect to convert 12:45 (hh:mm) into 12.45, because 12:45 is 12.75 hours, not 12.45 hours.